# Restrict brush to discrete ranges

Tags: javascript, user-interface, user-controls, d3.js, brush

I'd like to get a user to select a range of values using a `brush`. However, only discrete values make sense in my application, so I'd like to restrict the brush to these discrete values (integers, say).

One way of doing this is to use the approach described at [Ordinal Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349509). In that example, the brush itself can take continuous values, which are then mapped to the discrete values of the ordinal scale.

I would like to get a brush that snaps to discrete values while the user is brushing or dragging the brush. I came up with something that basically works: Rounding the `target.extent` and then reselecting the rounded range ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8X25N/1)):

```
function brush() {
    var s = d3.event.target.extent();
    if (d3.event.mode === "move") {
        var extentlength = Math.round(s[1] - s[0])
        d3.event.target.extent([Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5,
        Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5 + extentlength])
    } else {
        d3.event.target.extent([Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5,
        Math.round(s[1] + 0.5) - 0.5])
    }
    d3.event.target(d3.select(this))
}
```

[image]

However, this feels a bit clunky, and it leads to the undesirable behaviour that while the user is dragging the brush, the cursor can hover on the brush's edge, turning the cursor symbol from the "drag"-hand to the "resize"-arrow.

Is there a more elegant and robust way of getting a brush that only allows for the selection of discrete ranges?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I tried changing your fiddle to use the "brushend" event instead of "brush" with the same listener implementation and I think it feels a bit less clunky (smooth slide with snap on release) but it's debatable.

Answer (score 3):

This may be digging too much into the internals of the svg nodes that D3 uses to render the brush, but one solution is to select those nodes and change their cursor style. In your example, the generated nodes for the brush look like this (I trimmed out some of the attributes):

```
<g style="pointer-events: all;">
  <rect class="background" style="visibility: hidden; cursor: crosshair;"></rect>
  <rect class="extent" style="cursor: move;"></rect>
  <g class="resize e" style="cursor: ew-resize;">
    <rect style="visibility: hidden;"></rect>
  </g>
  <g class="resize w" style="cursor: ew-resize;">
    <rect style="visibility: hidden;"></rect>
  </g>
</g>
```

So for example, you could completely disable the resize cursors during a brush event:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush().x(x).extent([0.5, 1.5])
    .on("brushstart", brushstart)
    .on("brush", brush)
    .on("brushend", brushend);

function brushstart() {
  // disable the resizing cursor
  var resizers = d3.select(this).selectAll('g.resize')
    .style("cursor", "auto");
}

function brushend() {
  // re-enable the resizing cursor
  var resizers = d3.select(this).selectAll('g.resize')
    .style("cursor", "ew-resize");
}
```

As I said, this opens you up to danger that D3 changes the svg node structure for brush in future versions, but it's fairly simple conceptually and computationally. The `this` inside brush events represents the outer `<g>` node for the brush itself, so we simply apply selectors beneath that level to find the resize nodes.

Taking it one step further you could add additional logic inside your `brush` function itself to change cursors, but that's evaluated on mouse move so would be a lot more expensive.